# Update a table after an insert in SQL in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session, datatable

I have this code which inserts qty amount and item id into order details from a datatable session after order has been placed.

```
    for (i = 0; i <= dt2.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
        sql = "INSERT INTO details (ID, itemID, Qty) " + " VALUES " + " ('" + stroID + "','" + dt2.Rows[i]["itemID"] + "','" + dt2.Rows[i]["qty"] + "')";
sql = string.Format("UPDATE Items SET AvailQty = AvailQty - {0} WHERE itemID = {1}", dt2.Rows[i]["qty"],stroID);
        var _with1 = cmd;
        _with1.Connection = con;
        _with1.CommandText = sql;
        _with1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        _with1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

However, I am unsure of how to subract the qty from available quantity.

I have another table called Items which has a field `AvailQty` and I know how to do the query,

```
UPDATE Items
   SET AvailQty = AvailQty - Qty
 WHERE itemID = stroID
```

However I am unsure how to do that in this scenario as I am using dt2.rows?

Could anyone help how I could update the AvailQty from Qty please?

Comment: inside for put another sql command and execute it, sql = string.Format("UPDATE Items
   SET AvailQty = AvailQty - {0}
 WHERE itemID = {1}", dt2.Rows[i]["qty"],stroID);

Comment: I suggest you transaction scope it too, so if the order fails, the new Quantity wont be set

Comment: @DanielVorph Hello, I have done as you suggested but it doesn't seem to be deducting the quantity :(

Comment: I suggest you learn about stored procedures and transactions. using sql server without this knowledge is like riding a ferrary in 1st gear on a 10 mph zone.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have started recently, hopefully it will help me in the future, but for now, just need this quick...

Comment: Also, NEVER EVER use string concatenation to create sql statements when you can use sql parameters. This is just baging for an [sql injection attack.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: OP, your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection. Look into using Parametrized queries to avoid this

Comment: @whwuifhwui do you want it quick or do you want it good? You could be the smartest person on the planet, learning still takes time.

Comment: @whwuifhwui TransactionScope is extremely easy to use and essentially makes a set of operations 'atomic' so they either all succeed or all fail... to put it very simply.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I would like it good, but I don't have time currently to do it good :(

Comment: @whwuifhwui here's how simple TransactionScope is to use.... `using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    //transctional code…
    scope.Complete();
} `

Comment: Sorry everyone I know there's a lot of errors and problems with my code, I've only recently also started learning C# ASP

Comment: @whwuifhwui It's not a problem. I think we're just trying to point out how important these two concepts are - transactions & protecting yourself against SQL injection. You'd be surprised at how easy both are to implement.

Comment: @pep that does look relatively simple... something to improve on in the future. Could you possibly tell me why the second sql is not working, it inserts the data into the details table but not subtracting it...

Comment: Yes, I am always hearing about SQL injection, one of next steps to improve. There's so much to learn!! @pep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure should look something like this. (the c# I let you handle yourself):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OrderAnItem(
    @ID int, 
    @itemID int, 
    @Qty int
)
AS
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO details (ID, itemID, Qty) VALUES (@ID, @ItemId, @Qty)

UPDATE Items SET AvailQty = AvailQty - @Qty  WHERE itemID = @itemID 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

**Note** code written directly here, might contain mistakes